# WikiページURLを、VARCHAR( 255 ) に格納しようとするも途中までしか格納されない

Tags: mysql

**Wikiページのように長いURLを、MySQLのVARCHAR( 255 ) に格納したら途中で切れてしまいました**
・とりあえずTEXT型カラムへ変更して格納しましたが、通常は何のデータ型カラムに格納するものなのでしょうか？

・VARCHAR( 255 )と、TINYTEXTは同じ？
・TEXT型はバイト数指定した方が良い？
・BLOB型？

**知りたいこと**
・それぞれのデータ型のメリットデメリット
・バイト数を指定するメリットデメリット

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ・とりあえずTEXT型カラムへ変更して格納しましたが、通常は何のデータ型カラムに格納するものなのでしょうか？

HTTP/1.1 の仕様を定めた RFC 2616 では、URIの長さは制限がないことになっています。
http://www.spencernetwork.org/reference/rfc2616-ja-HTTP1.1.txt

とはいえ無限の容量を持つ型はありませんので、「ほぼほぼカバーできるだろう」という長さにしておいた方がよさそうです。

通常がどうなのかはちょっとわかりませんが、私なら VARCHAR(8190) くらいにするでしょうか。Apache が受け付けられるURLの長さがデフォルト8190バイトなので。
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#limitrequestline

なお、どの程度の長さのURLが許容されるかというのはブラウザにも依存するので、これが正解というのはなかなか難しいです。不安であればVARCHARの最大値（65,535）でもいいのではないでしょうか。

> ・VARCHAR( 255 )と、TINYTEXTは同じ？

型が違うので同じではないですが、データ記録時に必要となる容量は同じ（指定された文字列値のバイト数+1）ようです。
http://mysql.stu.edu.tw/doc/refman/5.1-olh/ja/storage-requirements.html

> ・TEXT型はバイト数指定した方が良い？

指定できないような？

> ・BLOB型？

バイナリデータ（画像、音楽、動画、など）を格納するための型です。
http://mysql.stu.edu.tw/doc/refman/5.1-olh/ja/blob.html

Answer (score 1):

VARCHAR と TEXT の違いなら昔下記のような記事を書きました

[VARCHAR と ～TEXT の違い - ngの日記](http://ngyuki.hatenablog.com/entry/20110804/p1)

VARCHAR で指定するものは『文字数』
TEXT は型ごとに『バイト数』が決まってます

Comment: 関連して、行が最大65535**バイト**であるために、 `VARCHAR(65535)` の列が作れない、ということもあるようですね（ストレージエンジンでも変わるようですが）。 http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/ja/storage-requirements.html

Comment: リンク先参考になりました。「どちらも255文字」の件、自分も疑問に思っていました

Answer (score 1):

現在URLの長さ制限に関する規定は取り決められていません。

RFC 7230～7237に置き換えられる前の RFC 2616(Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1) 
http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.2.1
ここでは無制限とした後で注意書きとして古いブラウザ対応の為に255以下推奨としてありますが、
置き換えられた後は255以下の記述がありません。
(昔は某ブラウザの対応が255迄だったのです。)

サーバー側の受け付ける長さは設定で無制限に変更できるので
ブラウザ側を参考にしてみてはどうでしょうか？

https://support.microsoft.com/ja-jp/kb/208427/ja
http://logicalerror.seesaa.net/article/383427331.html
制限の厳しいIEは最大2,083文字です。
WEB関係の制作でIEの対応を無視するとは考え難いのでこれを参考値として
文字コードやURLエンコードの差分を考慮して決めれば良いかと思います。

型についてはこの辺りを参照してみてください。
http://ftp.stu.edu.tw/Unix/Database/Mysql/doc/refman/5.1-olh/ja/blob.html
http://ftp.stu.edu.tw/Unix/Database/Mysql/doc/refman/5.1-olh/ja/string-types.html
http://www.dbonline.jp/mysql/type/